Set state after amp-list loads / set state using amp-list data
I am loading a list of options from our backend in an AMP email, and we are storing the selected option in a state variable which is set as the value of an <input> element. We would like to select the first element by default (doing this on a button press is OK), but we don't see a way to do this in AMP Email.
An example snippet:
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email data-css-strict>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <script custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js" async></script>
  <script custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js" async></script>
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
</head>
<body>

  <amp-list
    width="auto"
    height="100"
    layout="fixed-height"
    src="https://amp.dev/static/inline-examples/data/amp-list-urls.json"
  >
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      <div class="url-entry">
        <button on="tap:AMP.setState({ selected: '{{title}}' })">{{title}}</button>
      </div>
    </template>
  </amp-list>

  <input type="text" [value]="selected" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</body>
</html>

A few things I've tried (these all assume we are adding an event to the button):

When a button is pressed and selected is null, setting selected to the first item from the list response. But there is no way to get the data from the list.
Same as above, but trying to get data from the list from AMP State initialized with src. This is not available for the Email context.
Looking for some callback after the amp-list data loads to call a setState on. To my understanding, there is no callback on amp-list that is run after data loads.


I've read the question a few times but I'm still not sure I fully understand. I think it'd be helpful to refer to specific elements/buttons/text in the example snippet instead of using generic phrases like "a button" and "the first element".
The problem
If I understand correctly, the desire is to have an input element whose value is set to the first string in a list returned from an JSON endpoint. I don't think this can be achieved using just amp-list, because

amp-list unfortunately doesn't support a load event that the AMP document can listen to, retrieve the JSON in the response and save the JSON in a state for amp-bind to read.

Only the standard Mustache behaviors are supported in AMP for Email. In other AMP formats, The JS implementation of Mustache (mustache.js) is always used. In mustache.js, one can do a random access using syntax like {{array.0}} to access the first element. This is a non-standard Mustache feature which exists in mustache.js but not necessarily other implementations.
That combined with the use of the single-item and items="." attributes of amp-list and putting the input inside the template allows the Mustache template to render the default value of the input as the value of the first element of the array. The following works (and doesn't require a separate button click to render the default value) if it's rendered in the AMP playground, which uses mustache.js, but not in, for example, Gmail, which only supports standard Mustache constructs and doesn't allow random access on arrays:
<amp-list
  width="auto"
  height="100"
  layout="fixed-height"
  src="https://amp.dev/static/inline-examples/data/amp-list-urls.json"
  single-item
  items="."
>
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    {{#items}}
    <div class="url-entry">
      <button on="tap:AMP.setState({ selected: '{{title}}' })">{{title}}</button>
    </div>
    {{/items}}
    <input type="text" [value]="selected ? selected : '{{items.0.title}}'" />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </template>
</amp-list>



Approach 1
To achieve this in AMP for Email, the simplest design is to just modify the JSON endpoint to expose the default value as a separate top-level JSON property, say a property named defaultSelected, which is a sibling to the items property storing the array:
{
 "defaultSelected": "AMP YouTube Channel",
 "items": [
   {
     "title": "AMP YouTube Channel",
     "url": "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXPBsjgKKG2HqsKBhWA4uQw"
   },
   ...
 ]
}

Then, the above Mustache template can be modified as follows (single-item and items="." on amp-list are still required):
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    {{#items}}
    <div class="url-entry">
      <button on="tap:AMP.setState({ selected: '{{title}}' })">{{title}}</button>
    </div>
    {{/items}}
    <input type="text" [value]="selected ? selected : '{{defaultSelected}}'" />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </template>

The default value could even be exposed by a separate JSON endpoint, which can be used by a separate amp-list to render the input separately from the first amp-list that renders the list of options.
Approach 2
An alternative is to use amp-form instead of amp-list to fetch the default value, but this approach requires a button click to populate the default value of the input. It leverages the data binding feature of amp-form, and the input is moved to the success template of the form instead:
  <form method="get"
        action-xhr="https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/public/ssr_amp_list"
        on="submit-success: AMP.setState({'defaultSelected': event.response.items[0].name})">
    <button type=submit>
      Initialize
    </button>
    <div submit-success>
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <input type="text" [value]="defaultSelected" />
      </template>
    </div>
  </form>

(I had to change the XHR endpoint for the form submission to https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/public/ssr_amp_list because https://amp.dev/static/inline-examples/data/amp-list-urls.json doesn't work with amp-form in the playground. The latter responds with a wildcard CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, which isn't allowed when the XHR's credentials mode is include, which is what amp-form uses in the playground.)
